# Downgrade sudo package in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, apt, sudo

I just uppgraded sudo from 1.81.6 to 1.9.5 version and found out that the new version not work properly with SSH LDAP account, so I want to downpgrade by using apt install, but it not working.

```
root@sin-rcr01:/home/ubuntu# apt policy sudo
sudo:
  Installed: 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.10
  Version table:
     1.8.16-0ubuntu1.10 500
        500 http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.8.16-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://ap-southeast-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
root@sin-rcr01:/home/ubuntu# apt install sudo=1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
sudo is already the newest version (1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-66 linux-headers-4.4.0-66-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-70
  linux-headers-4.4.0-70-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-71 linux-headers-4.4.0-71-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-72 linux-headers-4.4.0-72-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-66-generic linux-image-4.4.0-70-generic linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic linux-image-4.4.0-72-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 375 not upgraded.
```

I also download sudo 1.8.5 package and install, but it just make a sudo package broken, I can not run sudo anymore and have to restore the server. Please advise me how to downgrade the sudo package, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

I installed sudo 1.9.5 from source:

```
wget https://www.sudo.ws/dist/sudo.tar.gz && \
tar xvzf sudo.tar.gz && \
cd sudo-1.9.5p2/ && \
./configure && \
make && \
make install
```

ubuntu@sin-rcr01:~$ sudo -V

```
Sudo version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers file grammar version 48
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.9.5p2
Sudoers audit plugin version 1.9.5p2
```

Comment: *I just uppgraded sudo from 1.81.6 to 1.9.5 version*: How? The outputs nowhere reflect 1.9.5. How did you install 1.8.16-0ubuntu1.2 version? Do you get any error while using sudo?

Comment: `apt install --reinstall sudo=1.8.16-0ubuntu1` this is the lowerst version I see.

Comment: @Kulfy: I just download 1.9.5 version and install by source. See detail below:
wget https://www.sudo.ws/dist/sudo.tar.gz && \
tar xvzf sudo.tar.gz && \
cd sudo-1.9.5p2/ && \
./configure && \
make && \
make install && \
sudo -V

Comment: @nobody:  it not work as well, see the output in https://pastebin.com/7gfPx29f

Comment: What is the output of `type -a sudo`?

Comment: @Kulfy
`sudo is /usr/local/bin/sudo
sudo is /usr/bin/sudo`

Comment: What about `/usr/bin/sudo -V`? Fortunately, `sudo` source provides uninstall options. If `/usr/bin/sudo -V` gives you `1.8.16....`, try `cd sudo-1.9.5p2 && ./configure && make && make uninstall`. If that happens to execute successfully, what does `type -a sudo` return now?

Comment: Great, I can uninstall by your suggestion and reinstall 1.8.16 version. But seen like downgration does not help me solve sudo issue with SSL LDAP user. I will create another topic for this issue. Thanks you